# ssrs 2008 to ssrs 2012 export to print on both sides of same paper

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

In a new ssrs 2008 report that uses sql server 2012, I am suppose to create a report that prints on both sides of the same paper. The first side of the report will display custom data with a mailing address for the customer.

The second side (back side of the paper) will contain generic information. The second side of the paper will contain areas for the users within my large company to fill out and return to the user via inter-office mail.

Thus my question is can this happen in an SSRS 2008 report to print in a PDF and/or Word document on both sides of the paper? If this is possible would you tell me if the paper needs to be exported to PDF, Word, or if this can on both format(s)? If so, would you tell me and/or point me to  a reference that will tell me how to accomplish this goal?

If this is not possible in SSRS 2008, is printing on both sides of the paper possible in ssrs 2008 r2 or ssrs 2012? If so, would you tell me what version of ssrs report would work, and if the print (export) needs to  be a PDF, Word, or either format?  If so, would you tell me and/or point me to  a reference that will tell me how to accomplish this goal?

If printing on both sides of a paper is not possible, would you tell me if you have any alternative suggestions I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Printing on both sides of the paper is a function of the local printer settings on the computer doing the printing. This is not a setting in Reporting Services and cannot be controlled from there. You can design your report with printing in mind (i.e. set up page breaks at the appropriate points, set page margins and the layout of the report items) but the actual print settings are dependent on printer/print driver being used and the settings of the local computer.

Comment: You mentioned the following, "actual print settings are dependent on printer/print driver being used and the settings of the local computer". Would you tell me what the print settings should probably be and what the settings of the local computer should probably be?

Comment: If you open up the "printer properties" dialog from any application, you should be able to set an option to "print on both sides" of the paper (if the printer supports it).